# Run Symfony Panther on web server

Tags: symfony, web-scraping, symfony-panther

I created a scrapper for various websites using the Panther library on Symfony. They are working on desktop, but when uploading the project on the web server it can't manage to start.

To keep panther standalone from what is installed on the machine I specified the path for the application binary and the drivers to file inside the project.

```
Client::createFirefoxClient($this->parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir') . '/drivers/geckodriver');
```

.env

```
PANTHER_FIREFOX_BINARY=../panther-binary/firefox-linux/firefox
```

On the webserver the function will stop and display Could not connect to firefox after 30 seconds error.

The webserver run on Linux 39ba1cf7fcd0 5.10.0-23-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-1 (2023-05-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux